# Can the Perl debugger save the ReadLine history to a file?

Tags: perl, debugging, history, readline

I work quit a bit with lib ReadLine and the lib Perl Readline.

Yet, the Perl debugger refuses to save the session command line history.

Thus, each time I invoke the debugger I lose all of my previous history.

Does anyone know how to have the Perl debugger save, and hopefully, append session history similar to the bash `HISTORYFILE` ?

Comment: just for anyone else looking for that: for readline to work in perl (ctrl-p / ctrl-n / ...) one has to `apt-get install libterm-readline-gnu-perl` (at least in debian)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way I do this is by having the following line in my `~/.perldb` file:

`&parse_options("HistFile=$ENV{HOME}/.perldb.hist");`

Debugger commands are then stored in `~/.perldb.hist` and accessible across sessions.

Answer (score 6):

Add `parse_options("TTY=/dev/stdin ReadLine=0");` to .perldb, then:

```
rlwrap -H .perl_history perl -d ...
```

Comment: @bitbucket: I've had enough problems in the past getting the built-in readline support working that I don't even bother anymore :)

Comment: What does `ReadLine=0` do here?`if false, a dummy ReadLine is used, so you can debug ReadLine applications.`,its document doesn't make much sense to me...

Comment: prevents the debugger from using readline even if the proper modules are installed; useful in the case where the program you are debugging itself tries to use readline, which would conflict (or as in this case, where you are using an external readline)

Comment: How can I enter commands to perl debugger if it doesn't `readline` in the first place?

Comment: Not readline-the-perl-function, but readline-the-library that provides advanced features like being able to use the up and down arrows at the input prompt to scroll through your past entries.

Comment: Term::ReadLine::GNU segfaults if i use the pager (useful for large vars, test with the likes of |o). Term::ReadLine::Perl works with pager, but neither GNU nor Perl packages maintain history across threads so i find them useless. rlwrap finally solved this issue for me. thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
$ export PERLDB_OPTS=HistFile=$HOME/.perldb.history
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following:

1) Created `~/.perldb`, which did not exist previously.

2) Added `&parse_options("HistFile=$ENV{HOME}/.perldb.hist");` from mirod's answer.

3) Added `export PERLDB_OPTS=HistFile=$HOME/.perldb.history` to ~/.bashrc from mephinet's answer.

4) Ran `source .bashrc`

5) Ran `perl -d my program.pl`, and got this warning/error

```
perldb: Must not source insecure rcfile /home/ics/.perldb.
        You or the superuser must be the owner, and it must not 
        be writable by anyone but its owner.
```

6) I protected `~/.perldb` with owner rw `chmod 700 ~/.perldb`, and the error went away.