# What's the difference between x and p in perl -d?

Tags: perl, debugging

```
  x|m expr       Evals expr in list context, dumps the result or lists methods.
  p expr         Print expression (uses script's current package).
```

They seems identical to me,what's different?

Also,is there any short cut like up/down arrow key in shell environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [perldoc perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html):

> p expr      Same as "print {$DB::OUT} expr" in the current package.  In
>                      particular, because this is just Perl's own "print"
>                      function, this means that nested data structures and
>                      objects are not dumped, unlike with the "x" command.

and

> Readline Support / History in the debugger
>          As shipped, the only command-line history supplied is a simplistic one
>          that checks for leading exclamation points.  However, if you install
>          the Term::ReadKey and Term::ReadLine modules from CPAN (such as
>          Term::ReadLine::Gnu, Term::ReadLine::Perl, ...) you will have full
>          editing capabilities much like GNU readline(3) provides.  Look for
>          these in the modules/by-module/Term directory on CPAN.

Comment: Why is `ReadKey` also needed?

Comment: Wow! +1 for the readline stuff -- I thought readline in debugger was perl's compile flag.

Comment: @Dallaylaen ,what do you mean by `perl's compile flag`?

Comment: @new_perl, no idea.  You can do it without installing modules like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433241/can-the-perl-debugger-save-the-readline-history-to-a-file/6433997#6433997

Comment: @new_perl: An option that was used at the time the *Perl interpreter itself* was compiled. You can look at those using `perl -V`. Typically things like readline, locale support, etc. are configured at compile time. Perl has shown its flexibility yet again.

Comment: It's flexible because the debugger itself is largely written in perl

Comment: @ysth,I tried `PERLDB_OPTS="RemotePort=localhost:7234 ReadLine=0 HistFile=/home/daemon/.perldb.hist" perl -d programe` but get error `Unknown option `HistFile' `,I'm using Perl 5.8.8

Comment: Probably not something supported in 5.8.8?  I've never heard of a HistFile option...

Comment: `8825     set_list( "PERLDB_HIST",
8826           $term->Features->{getHistory}
8827         ? $term->GetHistory
8828         : @hist );
`,I see such code in `perl5db.pl`

Comment: @ysth ,the code is just extracted from perl5db.pl,**what** do you mean `not in the 5.8.8 perl5db.pl`?

Comment: That code has nothing to do with HistFile; it is dealing in some way with saving/restoring your command line history for the current debugger session when you restart the program being debugged

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: `x` prints data structures, `p` prints scalar values. Try both:  `p {x=>1, y=>2}` is hardly meaningful, but `x {x=>1, y=>2}` makes sense.