# Is it possible to quit the debugger and resume from the same point later?

Tags: perl, debugging, dump

Is it possible to quit the debugger and resume from the same point later? For example, is there a way to dump the current state of a script being debugged (halted at some breakpoint) into a file, quit the debugger, then later restore the saved info into memory and continue the debugging process?

For example:

1. run `perl -d:SomeTool script.pl`
2. dump with SomeTool the state of script.pl into script.core
3. continue debugging from current breakpoint; exit.
4. load script.core with SomeTool into memory
5. continue debugging from current breakpoint; exit.
6. repeat 4-5 if needed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Perl debugger save the ReadLine history to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433241/can-the-perl-debugger-save-the-readline-history-to-a-file)